# Rust Decrypt from Python cryptography

Tags: python, encryption, rust

I used cryptography to encrypt image file in Python. The code is here:

```
import hashlib
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
import time

key = "secretkey"
keyBytes = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()

ivBytes = b"\xda\xe4\x87\xa7i\x8arbOC\xbd \x02\xbc*["

file_name = "1024.jpg"

with open(file_name, "rb") as f:
    imageBytes = f.read()

cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(keyBytes), modes.CBC(ivBytes), backend=default_backend())

encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).padder()
imageBytes = padder.update(imageBytes) + padder.finalize()
encryptedImageBytes = encryptor.update(imageBytes) + encryptor.finalize()

encodedImageString = base64.b64encode(encryptedImageBytes).decode()

encrpyted_file_name = "encrypted_image" + file_name
with open(encrpyted_file_name, "wb") as f:
    f.write(encryptedImageBytes)
```

and I got encrpyted_image1024.jpg. Now I want to decrypt this file in Rust. The code is here :

```
use std::fs;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;

use base64;
use crypto::aes::{cbc_decryptor, KeySize};
use crypto::blockmodes::NoPadding;
use crypto::buffer::{RefReadBuffer, RefWriteBuffer};

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open("./src/encrypted_image1024.jpg").unwrap();
    let mut encrypted_image = Vec::new();
    file.read_to_end(&mut encrypted_image).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", &encrypted_image);

    let decoded_image = base64::decode(&encrypted_image).unwrap();  // error

    let key = b"secretkey";
    let iv = b"\xda\xe4\x87\xa7i\x8arbOC\xbd \x02\xbc*[";
    let mut decryptor = cbc_decryptor(KeySize::KeySize256, key, iv, NoPadding);
    let mut decrypted_image = Vec::<u8>::new();
    let mut read_buffer = RefReadBuffer::new(&decoded_image);
    let mut write_buffer = RefWriteBuffer::new(&mut decrypted_image);
    decryptor
        .decrypt(&mut read_buffer, &mut write_buffer, true)
        .unwrap();

    let path = Path::new("decrypted_image1024.jpg");
    let mut file = File::create(&path).unwrap();
    file.write_all(&decrypted_image).unwrap();
}
```

I got the error : `` Err` value: InvalidByte(1, 59) `` in base64::decode(&encrypted)_image), and I found this error occurred because the bytes of image file is not Base64.

So I printed the encrypted_image like using `println!("{:?}", &encrypted_image);` and the result was:

```
[11, 90, 193, 68, 189, 179, 37, 240, 16, 87, 141, 123, 112, 213, 173, 242, 218, 0, 219, 151, 151, 53, 30, 96, 168, 90, 105, 62, 16, 52, 152, 8, 33, 2, 158, 52, 52, 112, 113, 203, 169, 32, 251, 203, 203, 177, 242, 199, 174, 203, 198, 111, 2, 54, 96, 207, 117, 115, 12, 18, 136, 189, 11, 155, 10, 79, 252, 122, 172, 208, 124, 116, 179, 34, 52, 239, 159, 142, 218, 153, 217, 224, 210, 225, 171, 190, 163, 7, 113, 67, 165, 6, 126, 47, 101, 43, 113, 254, 30, 201, 0, 192, 121, 252, 199, 39, 112, 119, 0, 48, 58, 124, 162, 124, 77, 115, 134, 40, 19, 172, 171, 165, 167, 14, 77, 155, 138, 48, 71, 157, 65, 146, 84, 130, 95, 79, 58, 45, 198, 164, 141, 249, 119, 25, 240, 149, 72, 129, 194, 31, 234] // it's too long, so I shortened..
```

In this situation, do I need to change using base64 encoding in Python code? Or Is there any way to decrpyt this kind of bytes in Rust?
Many thanks :)

Comment: In your Python code you encode the file into base64, but you don't use the `encodedImageString` variable. You write `encryptedImageBytes` into the file instead. And so you don't have an encoded file, and that's why Rust fails to decode it. Btw, why do you base64 encode the file? This looks redundant and costly. You don't need to base64 encode stuff, encrypted file is just bytes that you can work with.

Comment: To add on to the above comment, base64 is for when you need to transmit binary data in a medium that cannot represent binary data safely, but can represent text safely. Files stored on your hard drive _can_ store binary data safely, which is why there is no reason for using base64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I gave up this problem. I thought it's possible to encrypt in Python and decrypt in Rust, but there was something error between different languages.
Instead, I used 'magic-crypt' crate, both encrypted and decrypted in Rust.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @freaskish, I changed my Python code not using base64 encoding, and write `encryptedImageBytes`. Here's my Python code :

```
import hashlib
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
import time

key = "oingisprettyintheworld1234567890"
keyBytes = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()

ivBytes = b"\xda\xe4\x87\xa7i\x8arbOC\xbd \x02\xbc*["

file_name = "1024.jpg"

with open(file_name, "rb") as f:
    imageBytes = f.read()

cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(keyBytes), modes.CBC(ivBytes), backend=default_backend())

encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).padder()
imageBytes = padder.update(imageBytes) + padder.finalize()
encryptedImageBytes = encryptor.update(imageBytes) + encryptor.finalize()

encrpyted_file_name = "encrypted_image" + file_name
with open(encrpyted_file_name, "wb") as f:
    f.write(encryptedImageBytes)
```

and In rust, I put `encrypted_image_bytes` to `read_buffer` right away.

```
use std::fs;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;

use base64;
use crypto::aes::{cbc_decryptor, KeySize};
use crypto::blockmodes::NoPadding;
use crypto::buffer::{RefReadBuffer, RefWriteBuffer};

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open("./src/encrypted_image1024.jpg").unwrap();
    let mut encrypted_image = Vec::new();
    let mut encrypted_image_bytes = Vec::new();
    file.read_to_end(&mut encrypted_image_bytes).unwrap();

    let key = b"oingisprettyintheworld1234567890";
    let iv = b"\xda\xe4\x87\xa7i\x8arbOC\xbd \x02\xbc*[";
    let mut decryptor = cbc_decryptor(KeySize::KeySize256, key, iv, NoPadding);
    let length = encrypted_image_bytes.len();
    let mut decrypted_image = vec![0; length];
    let mut read_buffer = RefReadBuffer::new(&encrypted_image_bytes);
    let mut write_buffer = RefWriteBuffer::new(&mut decrypted_image);
    decryptor
        .decrypt(&mut read_buffer, &mut write_buffer, true)
        .unwrap();

    let path = Path::new("decrypted_image1024.jpg");
    let mut file = File::create(&path).unwrap();
    file.write_all(&decrypted_image).unwrap();
}
```

And this code didn't get any compile error, but I coundn't open the result, 'decrypted_image1024.jpg' file. I think there was something wrong in decryption..

Comment: In your Python code you SHA256 the key before using it. You don't do that in Rust. Try removing `keyBytes = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()` from Python.